# How can I add image from src attribute to gradient.xml file in Android?

Tags: android, xml, gradient

I am new to Android and I want to display image with gradient background. Is it possible to add an image into gradient.xml?

Below is the xml code for this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#631f68"
            android:endColor="#ff5555"
            android:angle="45"/>
    </shape>

</item>
```

Comment: As this is on UI, please attach a picture of what you would like to accomplish. Also maybe state your question clearly, because so far I read it as "is it possible to ..." and I would reply "try it out!" :)

Comment: you can create here image and than use in this selecter gradiend in layout file

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In your main_activity.xml,

set the background image for your topmost layout: (Relative or Constraint whatever you are using)

Then take another layout and give height and width to match_parent and apply the below Gradient to the background of it.

Gradient file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried it but still facing same issue not able to apply gradient to image. please look into my edited screenshot and code

Comment: @santosh Can you post a screenshot of how you want it to be..?

Comment: i have posted once check

Comment: You mean the second answer? @santosh

Comment: @santosh You want image like that screenshot?